# How can I split an image into multiple files with an action in photoshop?

Tags: image, pdf, split, photoshop, acrobat

I use Stamps.com to print shipping labels that are 2.4" wide. Stamps.com unfortunately will only generate a pdf of this size label with 4 labels on the sheet. It is not paginated, and will not print sequentially. Their template assumes you will print it out on an 8.5" x 11" label sheet and peel off from there. [Four Label 8.5x`11 sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39ojq.jpg)

I want to print on a thermal, continuous roll printer which cuts each label out automatically. To have this work I need each label to be one page, and the pdf with four labels split into four cropped files of 2.4" x 8.5". Any ideas?

I have failed so far in making an action in both acrobat, and photoshop. Should I be looking into solving this programmatically outside of photoshop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be inclined to do that with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows.

Unfortunately, you haven't provided a sensible sample image, so I'll provide a fake one. I have made the border yellow intentionally so you can see it on StackOverflow's white page layout.

[image]

Just at the command line in the Terminal, you would want to set the default density so that when **ImageMagick** rasterises the image it retains its quality. The `[0]` refers to the first page of the PDF. Then you would want to trim off the border - whatever colour it is (+/- a small fuzz factor to allow for variations in image encoding) and then tile into 4 equal horizontal strips. So, your command would be:

```
convert -density 240 stamps.pdf[0] fuzz 20% -trim -crop x4@ f-%d.jpg
```

and you will get 4 files out, called `f-0.jpg`, `f-1.jpg`, `f-2.jpg` and `f-3.jpg`

[image]

Comment: Your example is perfect, I was lazy and didn't want to modify exiting sheet...but how did you know you were trolling a Russian? And how did you know my file defaults to stamps.pdf? :-) I have this stamp I think in my collection even.

Cool program!

Comment: Tip from the top to anyone doing this in windows, you need to install GhostScript to interpret the pdfs or else it will throw an error like this, "FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin32c.exe""